# Push Notification Issue

Tags: iphone, push

In my IPhone app I am able to get push notification its appear a alert view. I want in that alert "view details" button when i will click  it navigate in a specify view. Is it possible?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well on click of PUSH NOTIFICATION alert you can navigate to application's specific view; but you can not add button inside that alert box.

For this you need to impliment two delegate methods.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

And

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

Fist one is used to check if the app was launched when  user clicks on a notification. If so, then in that method you can push the appropriate view controller onto the stack, just as you would normally with in-app usage.

For more details please check [apple's document here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4).

To see exact [sample you can](http://www.x2x1.com/show/8350178/how_to_open_different_view_controllers_on_app_launch_in_iphone_app_.aspx) go to this page which shows how you can bring view when user clicks on the notification.

Comment: which delegate will call when i will click that button ?@jigar

Answer (score 3):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Go through this site. It explains how to handle the below function clearly from where you can navigate to specific view

If App is in Ative/InActive/Background state

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

If App is not in Background:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```